# MongoDB Embedded Reference Duplicate Error

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am new to `MongoDB`, and coming from Sql database systems. I am confused about embedded reference's of mongodb.

I use Java Spring Framework and `MongoRepository` interface of Spring. I have a class (`User`) that annotated with `@Document` and has a String field (`id`) of annotated `@Indexed(unique = true)`. I have second class (`Device`) that has an embedded `User` object in it. It's like many-to-one relation (many devices may belong one user), however when I try to save second device with same User, application throws en error `E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.device index: user.id dup key: { : "5a8549fbeed7ae612d6a10d1" }.`

I tried making `User` object in `Devices` reference (with `@DBRef` annotation), and `@Indexed(unique = false)`, I could manage to save two devices. However, I dont want to use reference document, embedding document will be better.

I just wonder, is my approach wrong? Or my configuration was wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Transient` annotation over `Device.user` field if the user information is not relevant. If you need the User information in Device document try to use the `User.id` field (sql approach).